# Need to match three columns to get name from fourth

Tags: excel

I need to decipher a matrix of four columns, three of which are 4-digit codes that define the first column, or name of the vendor. In the query I can gather all of the codes (`System`, `Prin` and `Coastal`). I've built a matrix to help, but a new addition blew it all up. This was all done in Excel.

```
Channel Partner   | System Code  | Prin Code    | Coastal Code
------------------+--------------+--------------+---------------
Meat Market       | 9055         | 0100         | 0000 
Produce Store     | 9054         | 0000         | 0040
Fat Collector     | 9055         | 0200         | 0000 
Credit Card       | 9054         | 0000         | 0010
Paper Cost        | 9055         | 0400         | 0000
Togo Supplies     | 9055         | 0500         | 0000
```

Comment: and what exactly do you want to achieve? Can you give an example?

Comment: what is the addition you are referring to? how does the matrix look now? what you want to achieve?

Comment: I'm attempting to gather the correct Channel Partner name based on the the 3 code numbers, the problem I've ran into is the each code may have a duplicate code, but the matching of all 3 codes will give the Channel partner name. I can't figure out how to match each code and return the correct name. My query comes with the Codes but not the Partner name, I have to match the three codes to get that Channel Partner name. A new Partner was added with Prin 0000 amd Costal 0000 with a Sys Code of 9056. My Excel logic was fine until this code was added. I didn't know if there was a simpler method.

Comment: So I get 9055, 0100 and 0000, how do I get Meat Market, if I have to search through 18 different series of codes? The helper matrix looks very similar, albeit larger, than what I posted originally. Thanks for responding so quickly!

Answer (score 0):

For an effective lookup (eg of the combination shown in the image as C1, D1 and E1) it helps to have a unique key. This index I have constructed in ColumnA with this formula in A4 copied down to suit:

```
=C4&"-"&D4&"-"&E4
```

[image: SO26549056 example]

It is to the left of `Channel Partner` since that slightly simplifies the next step. I have chosen to separate the component elements with `-` purely for legibility.

The formula in B1 is:

```
 =VLOOKUP(C1&"-"&D1&"-"&E1,A3:B100,2,0)
```

This constructs the index (the search term) from the component elements "on the fly".

[VLOOKUP](http://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/vlookup.php).